# Which plants/trees will benefit from using urine as a fertilizer?

Tags: watering, fertilizer, nitrogen

[We know that urine](http://www.waldeneffect.org/blog/Using_urine_as_fertilizer_in_the_garden/) can [do a plant good](https://www.green-talk.com/urine-does-a-plant-good/). Certain plants (like citrus trees) will absolutely do well if you add urine to their intake.

But urine is very high in nitrogen and could potentially "burn" the plant. What are some common plants/trees that can flourish with urine as a fertilizer? Is there some way to tell which ones to avoid, lest they shrivel up and choke on the nitrogen?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if you have a low nitrogen compost pile (a lot of leaves, brush, etc), then adding urine there would be ideal. Sprinkle a thin layer of soil or finished compost over the top so that excess nitrogen is captured instead of being lost to the atmosphere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Urine is very high in nitrogen. One can observe how plants handle the quantities humans would produce by observing the yards of people with large dogs. Plants usually get "burned" from the quantity of nitrogen deposited by the dogs.

If your compost heap has a lot of straw/cellulose, then it probably needs more nitrogen. 
If you want to use your own stuff to fertilize plants, mix it about 50% with water in a bucket (or watering can) then apply it to plants. Fill the bucket/watering can indoors, and wash it out afterwards.

Comment: From what I've heard & read, 1 part urine mixed with 8 to 10 parts water tends to be the recommended ratio...

Comment: @MikePerry any tips how to mix them efficiently? ;-)

Comment: Shadow, pee in a bucket, add required amount of water, and voila!
It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

My Tomato plants get watered with urine 3 times per day. They thrive! This urine is not diluted - it coms from my night bucket; where a lot of water has evaporated;

Answer (score -1):

Any. Urine can be used as a fertilizer, however it should be watered down before application to prevent oversaturation of ionic minerals (sodium).

Comment: “Any” is not only too generic, but in fact false. There are plants that have adapted very well on nutrient-poor environments and don’t deal well with being exposed to nitrogen. Try a nitrogen-rich fertilizer on a carnivorous plant and you will immediately see the negative effects. Recommending dilution without further details is not helpful for any reader attempting to implement your suggestion.